# Is it possible to sleep in JScript executed by C# MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass?

Tags: c#, javascript, sleep, scriptcontrol

I'd like to be able to sleep in a JScript executed by C# MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass.  I thought that maybe the WScript.Sleep() function might be available, but I'm getting a "WScript is undefined" error message when trying that.  I'm new to scripting outside of a web browser.  I thought that MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass and Windows Script Host might be related, but maybe they're not.  If there isn't a sleep function that is available to the script, then what's the next best thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `sleep` function within javascript, maybe you can write a COM executable with implemented `sleep`-function or find one, which already has this function.

Answer (score 0):

The below javascript works fine for me to sleep within an MsScriptControl routine:

```
function sleepFor( sleepDuration ){
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration){ /* do nothing */ } 
}

sleepFor(10000); //10 seconds
```